# vaadin 7.7.14 applicacion is not working with MPR vaadin tool (Multiplatform Runtime)

Tags: java, gradle, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-flow

I have and applicaciont with vaadin **7.7.14** and I am trying run it inside a Vaadin 10+ Flow application using vaadin tool MPR (multiplatform runtime). I am following this documentation [Step-by-step Migration Guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/tools/mpr/introduction/step-1-migration-guide) and I am basing myself on the following example [vaadin14-mpr-gradle-demo](https://gitlab.com/mvysny/vaadin14-mpr-gradle-demo)

I tried with the followings gradle configuration but boths caused errors:

**A)**
**gradle plugins:**

```
id 'com.vaadin' version '0.14.8.1'

**dependencies:**

implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:14.3.7'
implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-core:14.3.7'
implementation 'com.vaadin:mpr-v7:2.0.5'
compileOnly 'com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.7.14'
implementation ('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.7.14') {
    exclude group: 'org.jsoup', module: 'jsoup'
    exclude group: 'com.google.gwt', module: 'gwt-elemental'
}

**result:** gradle tasks view is ok and project compile fine, but when start tomcat9 server it fail with the following error

GRAVE: Servlet.init() para servlet [com.vaadin.mpr.MprServlet] lanzó excepción
```

**java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.vaadin.mpr.core.MprServletService.(MprServletService.java:69)**
at com.vaadin.mpr.core.AbstractMprServlet.createServletService(AbstractMprServlet.java:183)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

**4)**
**gradle plugins:**

```
id 'com.vaadin' version '0.14.8.1'

**dependencies:**

implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:22.0.2'
implementation 'com.vaadin:vaadin-core:22.0.2'
implementation 'com.vaadin:mpr-v7:5.0.6'
compileOnly 'com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:7.7.14'
implementation ('com.vaadin:vaadin-server:7.7.14') {
    exclude group: 'org.jsoup', module: 'jsoup'
    exclude group: 'com.google.gwt', module: 'gwt-elemental'
}

**result:** gradle tasks view is ok and project compile fine, but when start tomcat9 server it fail with the following error
```

**GRAVE: Servlet.init() para servlet [com.vaadin.mpr.MprServlet] lanzó excepción
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No VaadinServlet discovered, make sure that you have removed Vaadin 7/8 legacy servlets from your application or make your custom servlet extend the new VaadinServlet instead.**
at com.vaadin.mpr.core.MprServletService.(MprServletService.java:66)
at com.vaadin.mpr.core.AbstractMprServlet.createServletService(AbstractMprServlet.java:180)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)

In both cases I have a custom UI and a custom vaadinServlet as follow:

```
    public class CustomUI extends MprUI {
   @Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request)
{
  super.init(request);
    }
}

public class PangeaServlet extends MprServlet{
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException
{
        super.init(servletConfig);
        CustomUI.timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
           CustomUI.closeInactiveSessions();
        }
        }, 60000, 60000);
}
}
```

Comment: One thing is that the plugin version should always be the same as the flow version. so in the first one it should be `0.14.3.7` and in the later one `22.0.2`. The PangeaServlet should not use MprServlet and be a Flow servlet. Also if there is nothing in the UI it should not be defined at all and if needed it should be used with the @LegacyUI annotation as noted in https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/tools/mpr/configuration/custom-ui

Comment: Continuing where @MikaelGrankvist left. There are number of version problems there. Notably Vaadin 7.7.14 is not supported with Vaadin 22.0.2 /w MPR. You need to have Vaadin 7.7.28 or newer. Also Vaadin 7.7.18 and newer, as well as MPR require Prime subscription of Vaadin. If you have one, you can also get direct expert support from Vaadin.

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist the latest vaadin plugin version is 0.14.8.1 as indicated in the following page: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-gradle-plugin so the vaadin plugin version 22.0.2 dose not exist

Comment: @TatuLund yes we are using a triel license to test our vaadin 7.7.14 application with MPR tool. Can you tell me please which vaadin plugin version , mpr-v7, vaadin-bom and vaadin-core should I use with vaadin-server 7.7.14?

Comment: The github.com/vaadin/vaadin-gradle-plugin is not official and each platform version ships a compatible gradle plugin since 20.0.0 https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.vaadin

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist ok perfect. Do you know which version of official/no official plugin, mpr-v7, vaadin-bom and vaadin-core version is compatible with vaadin 7.7.14?

Comment: `7.7.17` is still free and should work with vaadin `14.5.1` for which there is a published plugin `0.14.5.1` which then uses MPR `2.1.0` so that might be a functional version combination. Also it might be possible to get to `14.6.0` which has a released gradle plugin `0.14.6.0` that also uses MPR `2.1.0` and `7.7.17`

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist thanks, your information was very useful!. So to summarize and clarify the post. I undestand that I need first upgrade my vaadin-server from 7.7.14 to 7.7.17 because nowadays does not exist a version conbination of vaadin- plugin, mpr-v7, vaadin-bom and vaadin-core that is working with vaadin-server 7.7.14.

Comment: Looking at the changes between `7.7.14` and `7.7.17` there is nothing specific that would make it not work with MPR `2.1.0`. So It should be fine to stay on 7.7.14, but updating shouldn't pose any actual problem either.

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist perfect!. I tried the combination of versions suggested by you (vaadin-server: 7.7.14, vaadin-gradle-plugin 0.14.5.1, vaadin-bom: 14.5.1, vaadin-core: 14.5.1, mpr-v7: 2.1.0) and my project it is compiling fine and Tomcat starts fine. But when you call the UI page, it throws a UI related exception.                                            context with path [/ myApp] threw exception [com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.aunesa.pangea.MyUI] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.test.myapp.MyUI

Comment: Sounds like MyUI is not an MprUI, but with that info I can't say. I would still recommend to try to not use any framework UI.

Comment: @MikaelGrankvist I was able to fix the class cast exception error. Now the application is starting without errors at the server level but with an error at the javascript level. I understand that of javascript autogenerated by vaadinPrepareFrontend gradle task. The javascript error is the following: **(HierarchyRequestError) failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parents**

Comment: That sounds like a circular layout where something is added in multiple places.
PrepareFrontend shouldn't generate anything specific and only collects paths for the development time usage.